# OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 8, current size 7)

Tags: python, tensorflow

firstly, I'm really thankful for you to read my problem.

TensorFlow version: TensorFlow-GPU 1.14

os: ubuntu 16.04

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 8, current size 7)
     [[{{node shuffle_batch}}]]`

I'm testing a kind of CNN called "Goturn", and I implement it with TensorFlow. When I use 100,000+ images to train my net, it always displays this error. the strange thing is that the error displays during the training other than at the first circle of training.

I've already tried a lot of solutions from stackoverflow、CSDN and the other websites, but it is no use. most of the suggestion is to modify the elements of tf.train.shuffle_batch(), whereas how I should choose them, is there any regulation to obey? Thanks for reading. Any suggestion will be appreciated

```
def next_batch(input_queue): 
    min_queue_examples = 8 
    num_threads = 2 
    [search_tensor, target_tensor, box_tensor] =      data_reader(input_queue) 
[search_batch, target_batch, box_batch] = tf.train.shuffle_batch( 
    [search_tensor, target_tensor, box_tensor],
        batch_size=8, 
        num_threads=num_threads, 
        seed=88, 
        min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples, 
        capacity=min_queue_examples+3*BATCH_SIZE)
    print("next_batch!!!!!") 
    return [search_batch, target_batch,
    box_batch, input_queue[0], input_queue[1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I make such a stupid mistake, in fact, my dataset has a horrible error: some images are null, and when I delete those images, the code runs well!!!!!

Comment: This is not a stupid mistake, this is definitely something that happens to everyone :-) However, it does mean that you should close the question, so others see the problem is already solved.

Comment: To learn the rules and customs of Stack Overflow, I suggest you visit https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Happy coding!

Comment: @ItamarMushkin wow, thanks for your timely help!!, I will read it carefully and be familiar with it as soon as possible